# Linked Server SQL 2016: Can't update transaction in remote server

Tags: windows-server-2016, linked-server

I have 2 Windows servers EC2 located in different region. Both of them have public IP so they can communicate with each other.

In order to allow remote query, i created a linked server. Basically, they are in different region so i used their public IP as data source.
1st server IP: 13.xxx.xxx.xxx
2nd server IP: 52.xxx.xxx.xxx

I tested the connection and it was successful. Remote query also worked fine.
For example,
update table set number = 0 from [remote-server-IP].txtoc.dbo.xhead where
code ='1234'

But if i use BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION like this
BEGIN TRANSACTION
update table set number = 0 from [remote-server-IP].txtoc.dbo.xhead where
code ='1234'
COMMIT TRANSACTION

i got error.
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "linkedservername" returned message "No transaction is active.". 
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "linkedservername" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

I tried many methods
- Enable Distribute Transaction on both server from Component Service
- Allow them work through Windows Firewall
- Allow all traffic between them (setting in Security group and Windows Firewall)

But none of them worked.

Anyone can shed a light on this, please?

Comment: Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, and I stumbled across it and am only commenting, not an acceptable answer:

1) Public IPs for SQL are dangerous, you should keep that in mind. Between Regions you can do a route with a VPN at a minimum.
2) Make sure the DTC on the remote server allows remote connections - Start - dcomcnfg - Expand Component Services - Computers - My Computer - Distributed Transaction Coordinator - Local DTC (Properties on this) - Security - Enable Network DTC, Allow Remote Clients, Allow inbound, Allow outbound. 
3) If that doesn't solve it try dtcping from Microsoft to troubleshoot further.